# SSAS : An error occurred when instantiating a metadata object

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, cube

Aside from installing SSAS, I have no experience using it.

Our developers are saying that it is no longer possible to create a new aggregation, whatever the cube.

[image]

The error occurs when hitting Start.

Here is what I found in the msmdsrv file

**Type: 3, Category: 289, Event ID: 0xC1210012**

```
(7/30/2014 10:55:10 AM) Message: Errors in the metadata manager. 
An error occurred when instantiating a metadata object from the file, 
'\\?\E:\MSAS11.DWH_AS\OLAP\Data\Cube Fraude.0.db\MY_DATABASE OLAP.56.cub.xml'.
(Source: \\?\E:\MSAS11.DWH_AS\OLAP\Log\msmdsrv.log, 
Type: 3, Category: 289, Event ID: 0xC1210012)
```

The file E:\MSAS11.DWH_AS\OLAP\Data\Cube Fraude.0.db\MY_DATABASE OLAP.56.cub.xml has 0kb, so should this file be [removed](http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2011/05/ssas-error-when-processing-the-cube/)?

Any help on resolving this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was removing the empty files E:\MSAS11.DWH_AS\OLAP\Data\Cube Fraude.0.db\MY_DATABASE OLAP.56.cub.xml which allowed the aggregation to continue